# jQuery won't reload this div or recognise it's new PHP $_SESSION value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax to submit a form using a nonce stored as a PHP session which, as the name suggests, unsets itself and generates a new nonce every time it is used successfully. This works perfectly the first time the Ajax is run.

If I view the source on the page after running it, the new nonce is being updated correctly in the actual code, but for some reason jQuery refuses to read the new value from the `#nonce` div or update the display on the page with the new $_SESSION value.

The div holding the nonce and the submit button (index.php)

```
echo '<input type="text" id="nonce" value="'.$_SESSION['nonce'].'">';

echo '<div id="form-test-ajax">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="btn">
      </div>';
```

The jQuery functions in external file (functions.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btn').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
            url: 'adminapi.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'post',
            cache: false,
            data : {
                "action": "testAction",
                "nonce": $('#nonce').val()
           },
           success: function(data) {
             reloadNonce();
        },
        error : function(xhr, status) {
          alert(xhr.status);
          console.log("something went wrong");
        },

        timeout: 30000,
     });
  });

   function reloadNonce() {
       $("#nonce").load(location.href + " #nonce");
   }

});
```

The Ajax handler (adminapi.php)

```
 require_once 'inc/globals.php';

 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true");
 header("Content-Type:application/json");

 // Check if the request is an AJAX request
 function isAjax() {
   return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
 }

 if (isAjax()) {
   if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"]) && isset($_POST["nonce"]) && !empty($_POST["nonce"])) {

     $action = strip_tags($_POST["action"]);
     $nonce = strip_tags($_POST["nonce"]);

     // Validate nonce
     $securityCheck = validateNonce($nonce);

     // Nonce checked out
     if ($securityCheck) {

         admin_response(200, "Success");
         exit();

       } else {

         // Invalid nonce, failed
         admin_response(200, "Error : Security token was incorrect");
         exit();
     }

   }
 }
```

The other relevant PHP functions (globals.php)

```
 // Generate nonce
 function generateNonce() 
 {
   $_SESSION['nonce'] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
   return;
 }

 // Validate nonce
 function validateNonce($nonce)
 {
     if ($nonce == $_SESSION['nonce']) {

       unset($_SESSION['nonce']);
       generateNonce();
       sessionTimeOut();

       return true;

     } else {

       return false;
     }
 }

 // Set session expiry
 function sessionTimeOut() 
 {
   $_SESSION['start'] = time();
   $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (15 * 60);
 }

 // Deliver admin function response
 function admin_response($status, $status_message)
 {
   header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");

   $response['status'] = $status;
   $response['response'] = $status_message;

   $json_response = json_encode($response);

   echo $json_response;
 }
```

I've obviously left off chunks of irrelevant code PHP wise, `session_start();` etc as the PHP side of this is running perfectly. It's only the jQuery I'm having an issue with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JQuery **load()** method internally uses the innerHTML function to populate the matched element with the ajax response. So I would say it's not appropriate for your use-case, as you need to set the value of an input field, instead of update the html contents of a div. I'd check out the JQuery docs for more info: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro, I had already figured it out, but yes you are totally correct. The value needed to be updated in the dom directly, the page reload method didn't work at all.

Comment: No probs, glad you figured it out. I'd appreciate it if you marked the answer as correct in that case, if you feel that way inclined :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody else runs into a similar problem the answer was to return the new nonce in the ajax success response and then set the value to the nonce id.

Works now!

The jQuery

```
success: function(data) {

     $("#nonce").val(data.nonce);
     reloadNonce();
     ...
```

The PHP

```
 admin_response(200, "Success", $_SESSION['nonce']);
 ...
```

and..

```
function admin_response($status, $status_message, $nonce)
{
   header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");

   $response['status'] = $status;
   $response['response'] = $status_message;
   $response['nonce'] = $nonce;

   $json_response = json_encode($response);

   echo $json_response;
}
```